# Most optimal way to split up JavaScript chunks

Tags: javascript, webpack, chunks

I am in a dilemma as to how to split my javascript bundle.

Let's say the bundle is 1000kb. My intuition tells me I should split it into as many chunks of equal size as possible until the overhead of having a very small chunk introduces diminishing returns. This is with the assumption that we can benefit from issuing requests for each chunk in parallel at the same time, and so if we start them at the same time, we better minimize the size of the largest chunk.

So, that would result in, say, splitting it into 100 chunks of 10kb.

At the same time, 100 chunks seem like a lot to me. Perhaps the browser cannot handle that many requests at the same time.

So, it looks like there are several parameters here:

- number of chunks
- relative size of chunks

How should the two be optimized? Are there any additional parameters?

My current split looks as follows:
[image]

This is generated from:

```
  optimization: {
    usedExports: true,
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'all',
      maxInitialRequests: 8,
      minSize: 200000,
      maxSize: 500000,
      cacheGroups: {
        vendor: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          name(module) {
          // get the name. E.g. node_modules/packageName/not/this/part.js
          // or node_modules/packageName
          const packageName = module.context.match(/[\\/]node_modules[\\/](.*?)([\\/]|$)/)[1];
  
        // npm package names are URL-safe, but some servers don't like @ symbols
        return `npm.${packageName.replace('@', '')}`;
        },
      },
    },
   },
  },
```

No matter how I tweak the above numbers, the chunks never follow those bounds. How could I make them follow their bounds? What unit are these bounds defined with (parsed / gzipped size)? How can I get rid of the very small generated chunks?

Answer (score 2):

Think about chunks as files needed to be loaded **per page**, browsers having a limit of ~6 requests per domain, therefore, if your page requires more files to download, it will make the load slower.

Another important point, is browser caching, it doesn't matter what is the size of the chunk if it is cached for a long term in the browser, since it will be served from cache. This means that the size is not so important factor.
What affects caching? you should split your code into parts that changes more over time and parts that rarely change over time. For example, your components / styles probably will change more than `antd` dependency lib.

Last point, you can take out the consideration all chunks that needs to be loaded after some user interaction, since they won't affect your page loading speed (since they are loaded only after user interaction).